# Excel array formulas work for me but not for file recipient

Tags: excel

I created an excel model recently which uses some array formulas - vlookups and sumproducts mostly. On my end, everything works, but when I send it to my colleague who uses the model, the array formulas just throw value errors.

I'm using the latest version of excel, so I didn't use curly brackets. My first guess was that my colleague had an older version of excel. Curly brackets and ctrl+shift+enter don't help. Even after an excel update on their end, though, they still get the same error on the exact same file that works for me.

Does anyone have any idea as to what's going on?

Comment: Do you use the "," as the separator and they the ";" ? or vice versa?

Comment: When the Text function is used and there is not the same regional setting on both computers it can make problems. As solar mike wrote there can be differences when you have hardcoded some arrays, because row and column seperator are different in different regions. You could have posted some formulas.